# How insert data from list to MySql Database?

Tags: python, mysql

I have scraped data from a website using Selenium + Python.
It stores the data in a list and upon printing the list it looks like:

```
for x in list:
   print(x.text)
```

OUTPUT:

```
status1
some.email@email
status2
another.email@email
//There are more than 3500 elements in list.
```

I want to push the data into MySQL table which I have already created. The desired layout of MySQL table would be:

```
| ID  |  EMAIL             | STATUS  | TIMESTAMP          |
|-----|--------------------|---------|--------------------|
| 01  | some.email@email   | status1 | current Timestamp  |
| 02  | another.email@email| status2 | current Timestamp  |

//A lot of rows.....
```

I do not know the way to connect the database using Python and push the data. I've tried something like this, but I was unable to do the same.

```
import mysql.connector

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
host="localhost",
user="yourusername",
passwd="yourpassword",
database="mydatabase"
)
for x in list:
sql = "UPDATE customers SET Status='x'"
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: All that has been posted is a program description. However, we need you to [ask a question](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). We can't be sure what you want from us. Please [edit] your post to include a valid question that we can answer. Reminder: make sure you know [what is on-topic here](//stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic); asking us to write the program for you and suggestions are off-topic.

Answer (score 0):

first you need to install pymsql, once you intall pymysql then you can configure the conection in the next way:

```
import pymysql
import pymysql.cursors

your_host="localhost",
your_user="yourusername",
your_passwd="yourpassword",
your_database="mydatabase"
EMAIL="some.email@email"
STATUS="STATUS1"
YOUR_DATE="2018-08-03"

connection=pymysql.connect(host=your_host,port=3306,user=your_user,passwd=your_passwd,db=your_database)
cursor=connection.cursor(pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)
sql = "INSERT INTO YOUR_TABLE VALUES(ID,%s,%s,%s)"
cursor.execute(query, (EMAIL,STATUS,YOUR_DATE))
cursor.connection.commit()
cursor.close()
```

this is a very basic example, I hope this can help you.